# How to use the at() method in Pyomo

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I am using Pyomo and I have the following lines

```
outputVariables_list = [model.param1, model.variable1]
optimal_values_list = [[pyo.value(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list]
```

When I run it I get a warning that I don't understand:

```
WARNING: DEPRECATED: Using __getitem__ to return a set value from its
    (ordered) position is deprecated.  Please use at()  (deprecated in 6.1,
    will be removed in 7.0)
```

I tried the following line but this led to an error:

```
optimal_values_list = [[pyo.at(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list]
```

Further, I tried to use `pyo.value(model_item.at[key])` and `pyo.value(model_item.at(key)` and both lead to AttributeError: 'IndexedParam' object has no attribute 'at'.

How can I use the `at()` method recommended by Pyomo? What I don't understand is that Pyomo tells me to use "at" instead, but this not work as I get errors when using at. This is a quite confusing recommendation. Any idea how can I can integrate the at() method in my code?

**Update**: the full list of pyomo components that I use can be seen in the following line (the name indicates if it is a parameter, variable or set): `outputVariables_list_BT2 = [model.param_helpTimeSlots_BT2, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating_BT2, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW_BT2, model.variable_help_OnlyOneStorage_BT2, model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage_BT2, model.variable_usableVolumeDHWTank_BT2,  model.variable_electricalPowerTotal_BT2, model.variable_pvGeneration_BT2, model.variable_windPowerAssigned_BT2,  model.param_heatDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_DHWDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_electricalDemand_In_W_BT2, model.param_pvGenerationNominal_BT2, model.param_outSideTemperature_In_C, model.param_windAssignedNominal_BT2,  model.param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating_BT2, model.param_COPHeatPump_DHW_BT2, model.param_electricityPrice_In_Cents, model.set_timeslots]`

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal example that reproduces the issue.  If I create a model where `model.param1` is a `Param`, and `model.variable1` is a `Var`, then your original two lines run as expected without error.  My guess is that something in your `outputVariables_list` is a `Set` instead of a `Var` or `Param`.

Comment: @jsiirola: Thanks jsiirola for your comment. I added the full `outputVariables_list` that contains variables, parameters and sets. So the question is how to combine them in a list without this warning and using the `at()` method in Pyomo such that I can later just make a pandas dataframe out of is using `results_BT2 = pd.DataFrame(optimal_values_list_BT2)` Strangely Pyomo's suggestion with the `àt()` does not work and makes the problem even worse (from warning to error)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that for what you are doing (converting Pyomo components into `pandas.DataFrames`), you should not be using `at()` (nor should you be using `__getitem__` with the `Set`).

`Set.at(i)` returns the `i`th value of an ordered finite `Set`.  Pyomo originally supported this through the `__getitem__` interface, but that led to significant confusion with `Param` and `Var`, which are dict-like data structures.  As a result, the "sequence-like" API for accessing ordered Set members by position is deprecated and replaced by the less confusing `at()` method.  [I should also note that `Set` itself can support a dict-like interface: an `IndexedSet` behaves like a dict that maps an index to a series of scalar set data objects, much like an `IndexedVar` maps an index to a series of var data objects.]

Instead, you want a `components_to_dataframe()` function.  Assuming all the `Param` and `Var` components are indexed by the same Set (if they are not, then the `DataFrame` will not make much sense), you want something like:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pyo

def components_to_dataframe(*args):
    if not args:
        return pd.DataFrame()
    # verify consistent indexing sets
    _set = args[0].index_set()
    if not all(arg.index_set() == _set for arg in args):
        raise ValueError(
            "All components not indexed by equivalent Sets; cannot create valid DataFrame"
        )
    # we will be nice and label columns by their component names
    _names = [arg.name for arg in args]
    # It's easiest to create the transpose of the data block.  We will
    # iterate over the selected index set to ensure that if the
    # components are indexed by different (but equivalent) sets we will
    # still get the correct answer.
    _data = np.array([[pyo.value(arg[key]) for key in _set] for arg in args])
    return pd.DataFrame(_data.transpose(), index=_set, columns=_names)
```

That way, something like this:

```py
m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
m.I = pyo.RangeSet(0, 10, 2)
m.x = pyo.Var(m.I, initialize=lambda m,i: i*2)
m.y = pyo.Var(m.I, initialize=lambda m,i: i*10)
m.z = pyo.Param(m.I, initialize=lambda m,i: 10/(i+1))

df = components_to_dataframe(m.x, m.y, m.z)
print(df)
```

would yield

```
       x      y          z
0    0.0    0.0  10.000000
2    4.0   20.0   3.333333
4    8.0   40.0   2.000000
6   12.0   60.0   1.428571
8   16.0   80.0   1.111111
10  20.0  100.0   0.909091
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. To be totally honest, I think your answer is really complex and I don't really understand it. In my current code I just have one line of code that does all the things `optimal_values_list = [[pyo.value(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list] ` and the outcome always looks correct. But unfortunately i get the warning which I don't understand as everything has been working without problems (and I made more than 10000 runs). What is the advantage of using your complex method and is it possible to do this without it

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any comments on my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Thanks jsiirola for your answer. Any comments on my last comments?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind commenting on my last comments? I'll highly appreciate it and I'll be quite thankful.

Comment: @Any comments to my last comment?

Comment: Hi jsiirola, I still could not solve my problem. Can you think about another approach how to do it ideally with the recommended at() method?